# Using programmable keys in C#?

Tags: c#, registry, hotkeys, mousekeyhook

I am wanting to create a simple application that when running would wait for a specific key or combination of keys OR even button presses on a mouse. I am using the MouseKeyHook API in order to get this information, however I am running into a few issues.

This seems to work perfectly, as I can compare the string values of the Buttons with what I have saved. Now here is where the real issue begins. Whenever I press any programmable button on my keyboard I dont get ANY output? Why?

```
private void GlobalHookKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    HotKey.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString();
}

private void GlobalHookMouseDownExt(object sender, MouseEventExtArgs e)
{
    HotKey.Text = e.Button.ToString();
}
```

When Hooking using the MouseKeyHook API, I was able to get the two mouse buttons XButton1 and XButton2 but I got nothing for my keyboard buttons.

[image]

Comment: Programmable keys tend to use specific APIs that require manufacturer driver software.

Comment: @DavidG Sounds about right, but how can most Games detect these buttons and allow use of them and I cant without Driver software?

Comment: @FeaRCODE I could be wrong, but the only programmable buttons that I've seen working were mapped to various keyboard key combinations in the mouse driver.

Comment: Have you set up macros in your driver software for these buttons? Usually you set button X to perform action Y where Y could be a number of keypresses, you should be able to pick up those mapped actions.

Comment: @DavidG Actually I have not. And I just tested this in a game. My mouse buttons were recognized in the Game, however my buttons on the keyboard were not.

Comment: @xxbbcc I think you are actually correct. If you look at my answer to David's comment.

Comment: If this is the case though, how can the Mouse Buttons be working? And be Shown as `XButton1` and `XButton2`?

Comment: Mouse buttons are pretty generic, the windows API allows for 8 buttons. Any more than that requires specific vendor drivers.

Comment: Thank you @DavidG, If you would, post an answer describing what you told me. It would help others that have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmable keys on keyboard tend to use specific APIs that require vendor driver software. That software maps a key press to an action (or sequence of actions) that translate to standard operations. For example, press button X could correspond to pressing the `A` key five times in a row and your software should be able to pick up those 5 presses.

Mouse buttons are pretty generic and I believe the windows API allows for 8 standard buttons (see the [API reference here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645578.aspx)). Any more than that requires specific vendor drivers again and for those buttons to be mapped.